# What are the Presbyterian denominations in England?

Tags: presbyterianism, united-kingdom

Except the Evangelical Presbyterian Church in England and Wales and the Free Presbyterian Church of Ulster, both of which have a few congregations in England, I am not aware of any other Presbyterian churches in England. I know that the Presbyterian Church of England merged to form the United Reformed Church some years ago, but surely there must be some that did not merge?

Answer (score 2):

I'll describe the denominations you mention, for the purpose of completeness, but you've only left out one small denomination, from what I have found.  The denominations are:

- [United Reformed Church](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Reformed_Church) (founded 1972)

  - Formed by the merger of the Presbyterian Church of England and the Congregational Church in England and Wales.
  - Theologically liberal, and no longer exclusively presbyterian.
- [Free Presbyterian Church of Ulster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Presbyterian_Church_of_Ulster) (1951)

  - Theologically conservative (Westminster Standards, but permitting credobaptism).  Based in Ireland; only a small minority of its churches are in England.
- [International Presbyterian Church](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Presbyterian_Church) (1969)

  - Theologically conservative (Westminster Standards and Three Forms of Unity).  One of its four presbyteries is in the UK, of which several churches are in England
- [Evangelical Presbyterian Church in England and Wales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evangelical_Presbyterian_Church_in_England_and_Wales) (1987)

  - Theologically conservative (Westminster Standards).  About 20 congregations, most of which are in England.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest Presbyterian denomination in England is the United Reformed Church (it also has congregationalists).